# Simple Torch7 equivalent to numpy.roll

Tags: python, numpy, lua, torch

Is there any simple way of rolling a tensor in torch7 like numpy.roll and numpy.rollaxis in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the effects of numpy's `rollaxis` with torch's [permute](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-permutedim1-dim2--dimn). While `rollaxis` requires the start and end position of the one axis to move, `permute` requires the new positions of all axis. E.g. for a 3-dimensional tensor `np.rollaxis(x, 0, 3)` (move the 1st axis to the end) would be equivalent to `x:permute(2, 3, 1)`.

I'm not aware of an easy replacement for numpy's `roll`, but [scatter](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-scatterdim-index-srcval) seems like a decent candidate. Call it with the required dimension and the new order of elements after the shift. (Requires one new order of elements for each single row.)
The following example shifts each row of `x` (containing 2 rows and 4 columns with random values) 2 to the right along the last axis:

```
th> x = torch.zeros(2, 4):uniform(0, 10)
th> y = torch.zeros(2, 4):scatter(2, torch.LongTensor{{3, 4, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 1, 2}}, x)
th> x
 0.7295  3.2218  7.3979  5.5500
 8.4354  3.6722  5.5463  3.4323
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 2x4]
th> y
 7.3979  5.5500  0.7295  3.2218
 5.5463  3.4323  8.4354  3.6722
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 2x4]
```

Comment: Thanks, what about numpy's roll?

Comment: Thanks again, that would probably work but i'm working with very long tensors so it's not practical... So i guess if you had to implement rolling tensors of variant size in variant shift how would you do it?

Comment: For a 2-dimensional tensor `x` shifted by `n` columns you could use the following pattern (and extend it to n-dimensional tensors): `s = x:size()[2]; y = torch.Tensor():resizeAs(x); y[{{}, {1,n}}] = x[{{}, {s-n+1,s}}]; y[{{}, {n+1,s}}] = x[{{}, {1,n}}];` where `s` is the number of columns, the first `y[...]` command copies the last `n` columns to the first `n` of `y` and the second command copies the remaining first columns of `x` into the last ones of `y`.

Comment: I think it should be `y[{{}, {n+1,s}}] = x[{{}, {1,s-n}}]` but yeah that works!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy) so you can use numpy array in python and then pass it to torch module and convert it back.